# Linkedin/Facebook Api to get users comment on users out of network update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, linkedin-api

I am using `linkedin api` for getting network updates. And I am being able to fetch comments that a user made on either `his update` or on `his 1st degree network updates`.

My Question is : Is there any possible way to get the comment a user do on `out of network` update?
Thanks.

Update : Question for `facebook api`
It also would be helpful if anyone could lead me to a way to get users `recent likes` on friends' or non-friends' status/share on facebook. Those are shown on facebook profile page in recent activities block and/or on `activity log page` of facebook.Although it is possible to get if user likes a page/fan page.
Any help is appreciated.Need help..:-(Answer please...Thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question about the Facebook API.

You can get the current user's likes on status updates with this FQL query:

```
SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() AND object_type="status"
```

This will give you a list of the status updates the user has liked, sorted by time, with most recent first. This includes status updates only and not photo or video shares or any other object type. You can modify your query to a different object type by changing the type at the end of the query ("status") to one of these:

```
photo
album
event
group
note
link
video
application
check-in
review
comment
post
```

You'll need the

```
read_stream
user_likes
```

permissions for this query.

You can read more about the FQL 'like' table [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/).

Comment: Thanx for reply...I know that it is possible using Fql...is there any possible way to get likes using graph api.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: that only returns the list of pages you have liked..not the status and photos you like...:-(

Comment: The query only takes one object type. Please have a look at the object_type field explanation in the FQL page I linked to in my answer. According to the doc it isn't possible to use multiple object types as filter in one request. So if you want photos, it's object_type=photo etc.

Comment: no you got me wrong..i wasnt talking about fql...i am saying that...the graph.facebook.com/me/likes only returns the pages you like and not status or photos...

Comment: I see what you mean. I've deleted the comment with the Graph call url to  avoid confusing future readers. To sum it up, there is no equivalent Graph call to the above FQL call that I know of.

Comment: one more thing..is there any possible way to get the timestamp when this like was done.

Comment: Not that I know of. The FQL 'like' table doesn't have a 'created_time' field.

Comment: That i also have checked..that like table dont have created_time field..any other approch to get created_time for like using join or smthing else.